# Unable to pass date from c# to javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I'm dynamically building html table from c# code. Here is a portion of my code:

```
listHTML.Append("<td onClick='GoToHourlyReport("
    + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    + ","
    + deptId
    + ");' align='center' valign='middle' class='graph_red_grid_text'>"
    + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    + "</td>"
);
```

On `onclick` of the `td` I'm trying to pass a date to a JavaScript function.

```
onClick='GoToHourlyReport("
    + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    + ","
    + deptId
    + ");'
```

But when I pass a date like `2012-10-01`, I get a value 1999 inside JavaScript function all the time.
Can any one throw some light about what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the js function

```
    function GoToHourlyReport(date, deptId) {
    window.location.href = "CallAverageHourlyReport_BW.aspx?Date=" + date + "&Queue=" + deptId;
}
```

Comment: Well, it would be beneficial to see your JavaScript too.

Comment: Sounds more like the javascript function (which isn't shown) is manipulating the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View the page source, you will see your problem. You are missing quotes in the generated code.

In short you are doing

```
alert(2012-10-01);
```

not

```
alert("2012-10-01");
```

Add an escaped "

```
listHTML.Append("<td onClick='GoToHourlyReport(\"" + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\",\"" + deptId + "\");'...
```

Comment: well how to add " before date. I tried by adding a ' but it was rendering ? mark

Comment: Add an escaped " to surround the strings. Or use a string builder!

Comment: @jade, please mark this as the answer, both for the contributor and the community. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the date as a string, otherwise it gets interpreted as a number (2,010 minus 10 minus 1 = 1,999):

```
listHTML.Append("<td onClick=\"GoToHourlyReport('"
    + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    + "',"
    + deptId
    + ");\" align='center' valign='middle' class='graph_red_grid_text'>"
    + Convert.ToDateTime(dr["IntervalStartTime"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    + "</td>"
);
```

This should generate:

```
<td onclick="GoToHourlyReport('2010-10-01', 1)" ...>
```